# Max output voltage of battery

Tags: batteries

How can I determine the maximal output voltage of a battery (https://shop.righthere.nu/topfuel-power-x-1800-2s.html)? It has  \$1800\text{ mAh}\$ and \$35 \text{ C} \implies i_{\max}=1.8\cdot 35 \text{ A}=63\text{ A}  .\$

Comment: By asking the supplier, or by measuring one, if all else fails. But it should be in the specification. If it isn't, why waste your money?

Comment: The fact that the seller does not even mention the voltage of this battery pack is a hint to me. The hint is: do not buy here.

Comment: It is a 2s lipo battery, so probably 8.4V is the maximum output voltage. However, if you actually discharge at 63A, you will experience very rapid decline in voltage.

Comment: what does 2s mean?

Comment: 2s means 2 cells in series

Comment: @Neil_Uk Thank you.